# Elisp - Delete the only item in a list of length 1

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

In Emacs Lisp it seems that I cannot remove the last item from a list.

```
;; This works.
(setq list1 '(alpha beta))
(delete 'alpha list1) ;; => (beta)
;; list1 => (beta)

;; NOPE.
(setq list1 '(alpha))
(delete 'alpha list1) ;; => nil
;; list1 => (alpha)
```

Why?

Also if it is possible to do, how do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While `delete` does use side effects to remove the list element, it is not guaranteed to do so.  The correct way to use it is to assign the result back to the variable:

```
(setq list1 (delete 'alpha list1))
```

In fact, when I try your first example, `list1` also remains unchanged:

```
ELISP> (setq list1 '(alpha beta))
(alpha beta)
ELISP> (delete 'alpha list1)
(beta)
ELISP> list1
(alpha beta)
```

This is because `delete` is a function, not a macro or a special form.  This means that it cannot change the binding of the variable `list1`; it can only change the contents of the cons cell that `list1` points to.  If the list element that should be removed is the first element in the list, the simplest way to remove it is to just return the tail (a.k.a. the cdr) of the list.  If the element to be removed is the *only* element in the list, the correct return value is `nil` (the empty list), and there is no way to modify a cons cell to make it become `nil`.

You'll note that it *does* work if you remove the second element:

```
ELISP> (setq list1 '(alpha beta))
(alpha beta)
ELISP> (delete 'beta list1)
(alpha)
ELISP> list1
(alpha)
```

In this case, `delete` ends up doing `(setcdr list1 nil)`, which only requires changes the cons cell, not to the binding of `list1`.

Comment: I got my first example totally wrong. Thanks for the detailed explanation. On "delete does use side effects," are you implying I should be doing this a different way?

Comment: No, it's just to explain why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.  `remove` does the same thing as delete, except that it doesn't use side effects to modify the argument, but returns a copy of the list with the relevant elements removed, so then it would never work without `setq`.

Answer (score 5):

From `C-h v delete`:

> Write `(setq foo (delete element foo))' to be sure of correctly
>   changing the value of a sequence`foo'.

And apparently `'()` evaluates to `nil`.

How to do it then:

```
(setq list1 '(alpha))
(setq list1 (delete 'alpha list1))
```